# add-in communicate between instance

Tags: c#, ms-office, add-in, office-2010, office-2013

A use case: 
Two Excel instances are open and both are running the same add-in. Is there any way to let the add-ins communicate?

I need a tip or solution idea for Office 2010 & 2013 in C#

Comment: What do you mean by 'add-in' in this scenario? Do you mean a modern 'office store' add-in (previously called 'app') which only runs on office 2013+ or do you mean an old style VSTO add-in that works on all relatively recent versions of office? If you mean a modern office store add-in I think I can help.